# Dump list of installed programs to a text file

Tags: windows, command-line

I need a command line utility which dumps names of installed programs on OS into a text file. I tried **Windows System Dump Utility 1.0 Build 200** however it's aimed to hardware info and cannot do what I want.

- It is prefered the names on Programs and Features list
- The format can be txt, csv or any other known format

Comment: I fixed my problem some time ago using c# itself. My code gets start menu items.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner). It's uninstallation dialog has an option to export such a list. See instructions here:

https://www.howtogeek.com/165293/how-to-get-a-list-of-software-installed-on-your-pc-with-a-single-command/

... which also has instructions for how to do with just Windows Powershell.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried those explanations about PowerShell so much and tired of doing it. they don't give me exact results.

Answer (score 2):

[WinAudit](http://www.parmavex.co.uk/winaudit.html) can do exactly what you need, is free and will also include details such as licence and ports used.

- EUPL
- Save as csv, rtf and html
- WinAudit is an inventory utility for Windows computers. It creates a comprehensive report on a machine's configuration, hardware and software. WinAudit is free, open source and can be used or distributed by anyone. It is used by IT experts in academia, government, industry as well as security conscious professionals in the armed services, defence contractors, electricity generators and police forces.
- WinAudit is open-source free software made with other free software

[image]

Comment: it doesnt give me exact result. I mean some of the installed programs doesn't appear in dump file.

Comment: Programs that are "installed" by just being unpacked & copied to the hard drive without being added to the path or making registry changes may not show up @onurcano22 the only way to get them is to search the hard drive for all executable files, I even know some that do not show up well even then as they are actually script based.

Comment: Does someone know how to add a "header" line with WinAudit.exe commandline for CSV? I only get the raw data without columndescription if I use ´.../f=computer_audit.csv´